# Bluetooth option grayed out in newly installed Ubuntu 16.04.1, but status shows active

Tags: xubuntu, bluetooth

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 version and after that Bluetooth app option is grayed out and not able to turn on Bluetooth or connect with devices.

I ran

```
 sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

and changed `#AutoEnable=false` to `AutoEnable=true` at the bottom of the file, then ran

```
 sudo service /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

And I tried with Bluetooth restart service also.

```
 sudo service bluetooth status
 ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor  
 preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-10-15 13:43:24 IST; 5h 4min ago
 Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 4666 (bluetoothd)
  Status: "Running"
 CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
       └─4666 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd  
 Oct 15 13:43:24 prakash-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Starting 
  Bluetooth service...
  Oct 15 13:43:24 prakash-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC bluetoothd[4666]:  
  Bluetooth daemon 5.37
  Oct 15 13:43:24 prakash-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Started 
  Bluetooth service.
  Oct 15 13:43:24 prakash-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC bluetoothd[4666]: 
  Starting SDP server
  Oct 15 13:43:24 prakash-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC bluetoothd[4666]: 
  Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```